# exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: in /app/Mage.php:594

Tags: magento-1.8

I create a module where I want to extend product review controller for fetch all reviews in one custom page. I first extend ProductController.php. My controller is

```
require_once Mage::getModuleDir('controllers', 'Mage_Review').DS.'ProductController.php';
class Bh_Customreview_ProductController extends Mage_Review_ProductController
{
   public function indexAction()
   {
      $this->loadLayout();
      $this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Customer Reviews"));
      $this->renderLayout();
   }
```

Then I create a block in **app/code/local/Bh/Customreview/Block/Product/Allreview.php** where I create a custom collection as my wish.

```
class Bh_Customreview_Block_Product_Allreview extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{    

 public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $collection = $this->getAllreview();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(2=>2,'all'=>'all'));
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getCollection()->load();
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    public function getAllreview()
    {
         $this->_allreviewsCollection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->addRateVotes()
                ->setDateOrder();
                return $this->_allreviewsCollection;
    }
}
```

my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Bh_Customreview>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Bh_Customreview>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customreview>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Bh_Customreview</module>
                    <frontName>customreview</frontName>
                </args>
            </customreview>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customreview>
                    <file>customreview.xml</file>
                </customreview>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <rewrite>
            <customreview>
                <from><![CDATA[ #^/review/product/# ]]></from>
                <to>/customreview/product/</to>
            </customreview>
        </rewrite>
        <helpers>
            <customreview>
                <class>Bh_Customreview_Helper</class>
            </customreview>
        </helpers>
        <blocks>
            <customreview>
                <class>Bh_Customreview_Block</class>
            </customreview>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <customreview_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Bh_Customreview</module>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </customreview_setup>
            <customreview_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </customreview_write>
            <customreview_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </customreview_read>            
        </resources> 
        <template>
            <email>
                <product_write_review_email module="Bh_customreview">
                    <label>Product Write Review Email</label>
                    <file>product_write_review.html</file>
                    <type>html</type>
                </product_write_review_email>
            </email>
        </template>
    </global>
</config>
```

layout.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <review_product_index translate="label">
        <label>All  Product Reviews List</label>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/1column.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">   
            <block type="customreview/product_allreview" name="customreview_product_allreview" template="customreview/product/view/allreview.phtml"/>   
        </reference> 
    </review_product_index>
```

**Exception  Error :**

```
 exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Invalid block type: Bh_Customreview_Block_Product_Allreview' in /home2/mobilevi/public_html/web/app/Mage.php:594
```

Anything wrong by me?

Comment: GUdduu,kemn aachis?

Comment: fine. please give me answer. This one also work on my local server.

Comment: there are may be spacing issue

Comment: same module work on lamp server, error getting on live  server. which file???

Comment: cofig.xml issue

Comment: check my config.xml file, There are no issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20161/discussion-between-u2460470-and-amit-bera).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**benmarks** is  right, I have fix my problem after spend two or three hours  on googling.

Actually my problem was Magento compilation, 
From my experience, need to disable magento **compilation** when you register new module in magento.

In general, Create Hosting customers shouldn't need compilation enabled, since our Magento Hosting Plans come pre-configured and optimised with APC cache. However, if you accidentally enabled compilation, or if you are actively using compilation instead of APC Cache and need to disable compilation to perform an upgrade, install or remove an extension etc, then you will need to disable it again.
There are two ways in which this can be done:

**1. Via Magento admin**
Navigate to System > Tools > Compilation page and click on Disable button
Navigate to System > Cache Management screen and use Flush Cache button.

2. Via SFTP, by editing the includes/config.php file

To disable compilation in Magento, edit includes/config.php. At around line 28, uncomment the first line and comment out the second:

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

**3. Via SSH**

```
php -f shell/compiler.php -- disable
php -f shell/compiler.php -- clear
```

Check the status:

```
# php -f shell/compiler.php -- state
Compiler Status:          Disabled
Compilation State:        Not Compiled
Collected Files Count:    0
Compiled Scopes Count:    0
```

Clear the cache:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/session/*
```

Answer (score 1):

Where to start?

In your comment with Amit you say this works on one server but not another. That speaks to one of the following (check these first):

1. Cache not cleared (including APC)
2. Incomplete file upload
3. **Difference in filesystem case sensitivity**

For  #3 you want to check that all folders and files under *`app/code/local/Bh/`* begin with an uppercase letter and are followed only by lowercase letters *unless* there are camel-cased arguments (which I do not see in your config, layout, or code samples).

If this doesn't work, I'd suggest simplifying your block definition by removing queries to rule out an error from the model layer.

Hopefully the above is helpful. I want to go ahead and address a number of issues I see with your module to save you some time & to educate.

## Config

Your config has a few issues. First thing to tackle is the rewrite approach you are using, which is old and deprecated:

```
<global>
    <rewrite>
        <customreview>
            <from><![CDATA[ #^/review/product/# ]]></from>
            <to>/customreview/product/</to>
        </customreview>
    </rewrite>
</global>
```

Better to use...

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <review>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Bh_Customreview before="Mage_Review">Bh_Customreview</Bh_Customreview>
                    <!-- I prefer to put rewrites under somewhere else by specifying an additional folder, e.g. Bh_Customreview_Rewrites -->
                </modules>
            </args>
        </review>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

...and then consider that you could remove your module's `routers` declaration as it is not needed.

You will have an error with your `//product_write_review_email` node because of a typo in the `module` attribute has a typo (`Bh_customreview` rather than `customreview` - remember that this will be used to instantiate a helper.

Also, your `//customreview_read` and `//customreview_write` nodes are superfluous.

## Block

Core code is sometimes doesn't follow its own conventions, but see the following edited version of your block comments for suggestions:

```
class Bh_Customreview_Block_Product_Allreview extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    //convention is to do setup in "protected single underscore construct"
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $collection = $this->getAllreview();
        $this->setCollection($collection);
    }

    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();

        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'custom.pager');
        $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(2=>2,'all'=>'all'));
        $pager->setCollection($this->getCollection());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        //$this->getCollection()->load(); <!-- leave that out, let rendering lazy-load it -->
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }

    public function getAllreview()
    {
         $this->_allreviewsCollection = Mage::getModel('review/review')->getCollection()
                ->addStoreFilter(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->addStatusFilter(Mage_Review_Model_Review::STATUS_APPROVED)
                ->addRateVotes()
                ->setDateOrder();
        return $this->_allreviewsCollection;
    }
}
```

As a matter of style... from your controller class:

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock("head")->setTitle($this->__("Customer Reviews"));
```

Certainly nothing *really* wrong doing it this way, but you could add this to your layout XML (note other changes inline as well):

```
<layout><!-- "version" is never evaluated -->
    <review_product_index>
        <!-- no need to redeclare the translate/label pairing -->
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <!-- this does the same thing as your controller, just more conventionally -->
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="Bh_Customreviews">
                <title>Customer Reviews</title>
            </action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">   
            <block type="customreview/product_allreview" name="customreview_product_allreview" template="customreview/product/view/allreview.phtml"/>   
        </reference> 
    </review_product_index>
</layout>
```

You'll want to go ahead and declare a translation file for your module as well:

```
<frontend>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Bh_Customreview>
                <files>
                    <default>Bh_Customreview.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Bh_Customreview>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</frontend>
```